# Profit by programming a Bitcoin service (wallet) in an "only-now" bc adopting country?

Tags: development, e-wallet, website-integration, business

A country where I am from appears to take Bitcoin into an interest right now.

I am a senior programmer at one company and have done several projects, but right now I am mostly interested in the opportunities that might appear from Bitcoin to a programmer at my small european country.

I appear to have a domain bitcoin.abc and bitcoins.abc, where abc stands for my country tld name.

I went to freenode chat #bitcoin, #startups, asked out several people, but could not find any helpful information about an opportunities that one might get in my case.

I wonder if there is anything I can use such domain names and a programming knowledge, with interest in such a decentralized system and get on a way to profit.

I don't really know, but, perhaps building a new wallet, or such? I would really appreciate any ideas, thoughts or resources to read for me on my case. Thanks.

Comment: Why would anyone give you an idea to implement? If I would have a nice idea, I would do it myself. Having a domain is not really such a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Use your domain to sell bitcoins for fiat in your country. That's the most profitable thing you can do.